# JQuery Hide and Show Text based on Checkbox Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table that is loaded as a partial, I have AJAX callbacks to load the table when either the pagination is selected or display number of items. I would like to hide the text until a checkbox is selected. Then show the text which has a count, and a total count of records in the table. The second part is that I have a link that when pressed allows you to select all items in the table.

I need some help with this, some of my Jquery:

```
 $(".individual").on("change", check);

        function check() {
            $(".records-selected").hide();
            $("#selected").text($(".individual:checked").length);
            $("#total").text($(".individual").length);
        }
        check();
```

Text:

```
<li><p class="records-selected"><span id="selected"></span> of <span id="total"></span> records selected</li>
            <li><a href="#" class="number-records">Select All 29 Records</a></li>
```

Each checkbox has a class of **individual** and the select all has a class of **selectall**

I also need to disable a button called .btn2 if one checkbox is selected. Then if multiple checkboxes are selected then .btn1 is enabled and .btn2 is disabled.

Any idea on the best way to do this?

Comment: can you please clarify the specific issue?

Comment: I need to disable my text until a checkbox is selected.

`li><p class="records-selected"><span id="selected"></span> of <span id="total"></span> records selected</li>
   <li><a href="#" class="number-records">Select All 29 Records</a></li>`

Some JQuery so far:

`$(".individual").on("change", check);

  function check() {
   $(".records-selected").hide().on(".individual:checked").show();
   $("#selected").text($(".individual:checked").length);
   $("#total").text($(".individual").length);
  }
  check();`

Comment: please add code into your question, not comments. Anyway the "best" way is subjective - are you having a specific problem with your code, or just wondering if it's efficient?

Comment: I am wondering what would be the best approach, as I am unsure how to do it. I have added my code so far.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work yet? It's not clear. Please give us a specific description of your problem. Speculating as to what is "best" is no good - like I said we don't deal in subjective questions. Everyone's definition of "best" is different.

Comment: Its okay I have got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Checks individual checkboxes and displays the count
    $(".individual").on("change", check);

    function check() {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 0) {
            $(".records-selected").show();
            $("#selected").text($(".individual:checked").length);
            $("#total").text($(".individual").length);
        }
        else {
            $(".records-selected").hide();
        }
    }
    check();
```